# MMDrawerController - How to Master-Detail SideBar

Tags: ios, tableview, sidebar, master-detail

How can I use the [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) for my Master-Detail Application?

I want the `DetailViewController` as my `centerViewController` and the `MasterViewController` as a `leftDrawerViewController`.

Actually this is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MMDrawerController.h"
#import "MMDrawerVisualState.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) MMDrawerController * drawerController
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:              (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
     UIViewController * leftDrawer = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
     UIViewController * center = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];


     UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:center];
     [navigationController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMExampleCenterNavigationControllerRestorationKey"];

     self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                         initWithCenterViewController:center
                         leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer];
     [self.drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];
     [self.drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:200.0];
     [self.drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
     [self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];

     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     [self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];
     // Override point for customization after application launch.
     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}
```

The centerViewController stays completely black and the leftDrawerViewController only contains a tableView.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with your code. I implemented it in a test app and it displayed just fine. Did you check the center view properties to investigate the center controller appearing black?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `MMDrawerController` try setting the `initWithCenterViewController` parameter to the `navigationController` instead of `center`.